# Firebase Create and Login?

Tags: python, firebase

Can I use firebase with python to do user account creation and logging in and out?

or any other recommendations? I've read but seems like it only uses nodejs

Comment: I would recommend doing a more extensive search before posting general questions like this as your question might be down voted by moderators. For instance, a simple google and search in Firebase documentation leads to https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-firebase/1.2 and https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/.I would encourage you to use node.js though as the APIs have been extensively expanded.

Comment: "it only uses nodejs"... Firebase has many other client APIs

Answer (score 2):

There is an Admin SDK for Python for certain Firebase products, including Firebase Authentication.

The Admin SDK for Firebase is meant to run on servers and in other trusted environments. This means that a process using the Admin SDK has administrative access to all Firebase services. This for example allows you to easily [create a new user account with the Python SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.auth#create_user).

But that also means that the Python SDK cannot be used to sign in with Firebase Authentication: after all, the process already runs with administrative privileges.

If you want to use the Python SDK to verify users, you should have the users sign in on the client with one of the regular Firebase Authentication SDKs. Then send the ID token from the client to your server, and [use the Python SDK to verify that token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.auth#verify_id_token).